# Почему не устанавливается Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

Делаю все по [документации](https://github.com/garyjob/Setup-Wiki/blob/master/postgresql), но при запуске команды `sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.2 libpq-dev` такие ошибки:

```
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
E: Не удалось найти пакет postgresql-9.2
E: Не удалось найти пакет по регулярному выражению «postgresql-9.2»
```

Также при такой команде `sudo apt-get update`:

```
W: Недоступен открытый ключ для следующих ID ключей:
1397BC53640DB551
W: Не удалось получить http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/dists/YOUR_UBUNTU_VERSION_HERE-pgdg/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 217.196.149.55 80]

W: Не удалось получить http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/dists/YOUR_UBUNTU_VERSION_HERE-pgdg/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 217.196.149.55 80]

W: Не удалось получить http://ppa.launchpad.net/pitti/postgresql/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Не удалось получить http://ppa.launchpad.net/pitti/postgresql/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Не удалось получить http://ppa.launchpad.net/pitti/postgresql/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Некоторые индексные файлы не скачались. Они были проигнорированы или вместо них были использованы старые версии.
```

**Update**

Командой `lsb_release -c` узнал свою версию Ubuntu, прописал ее в файл /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list как сказано в инструкции, и теперь при `sudo apt-get update` вылазят уже такие ошибки:

```
W: Недоступен открытый ключ для следующих ID ключей:
1397BC53640DB551
W: Не удалось получить http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/dists/rafaela-pgdg/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 213.189.17.228 80]

W: Не удалось получить http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/dists/rafaela-pgdg/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 213.189.17.228 80]

W: Не удалось получить http://ppa.launchpad.net/pitti/postgresql/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Не удалось получить http://ppa.launchpad.net/pitti/postgresql/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Не удалось получить http://ppa.launchpad.net/pitti/postgresql/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Некоторые индексные файлы не скачались. Они были проигнорированы или вместо них были использованы старые версии.
```

Все делал уже по этой [инструкции](http://pgcookbook.ru/article/install_latest.html), там вторым пунктом добавление репозитория.

**Update 2**
Определил, что Linux Mint 17.2 собрана на базе Ubuntu 14.04. Значит в адрес репозиториев написал trusty. Вышла такая строчка - deb apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt trusty-pgdg main

```
W: Недоступен открытый ключ для следующих ID ключей:
1397BC53640DB551
W: Не удалось получить http://ppa.launchpad.net/pitti/postgresql/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Не удалось получить http://ppa.launchpad.net/pitti/postgresql/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Не удалось получить http://ppa.launchpad.net/pitti/postgresql/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Некоторые индексные файлы не скачались. Они были проигнорированы или вместо них были использованы старые версии.
```

Comment: Принципиально установить именно эту версию? Если не сложно, укажите версию операционной системы. Вы используете Ubuntu?

Comment: @cheops Не принципиально.
Distributor ID: LinuxMint
Description: Linux Mint 17.2 Rafaela
Release: 17.2
Codename: rafaela

Comment: `lsb_release -c` вам выдал версию LM, а не Ubuntu. Я ж написал ниже, ищите package base, на базе которой собрана ваша версия дистрибутива.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
YOUR_UBUNTU_VERSION_HERE
```

Не смущает? При добавлении репозиториев вы забыли существенный шаг: замена этого кусочка на первое слово кодового имени вашей версии Ubuntu. Для 14.04, например, это `trusty`, от Trusty Tahr.

И вообще, **выкиньте эти невесть откуда взятые инструкции**. Там ссылаются на PPA, [не обновлявшийся с 2012 года](http://ppa.launchpad.net/pitti/postgresql/ubuntu/dists/) (спасибо [@KoVadim](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/2739/kovadim) за улики). Даже [на странице этого PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Epitti/+archive/ubuntu/postgresql) чётко сказано:

> **[Deprecated]** PostgreSQL backports for stable Ubuntu releases
>
> ATTENTION: The functionality of this has been **moved to http://apt.postgresql.org**,

---

Во-первых, PostgreSQL **есть в системных репозиториях**. Пакет называется просто `postgresql`, в Trusty поставляется версия 9.3.

Во-вторых, если всё-таки нужна версия, которой в системных репозиториях нет, есть [страница на вики PostgreSQL](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt), где описана процедура добавления репозиториев *PostgreSQL Global Development Group* (PGDG), которые **считаются официальными**.

Comment: У меня Linux Mint. Не совсем понимаю, когда нужно было прописывать первое слово кодового имени ОС

Comment: @MaximCherevatov ищите, какая у вашей версии "package base", LM же собран на базе Ubuntu. Прописывать их нужно было в адреса репозиториев, которые вы скопировали из инструкции по установке.

Comment: добавил обновление

Comment: @MaximCherevatov вы **НЕ** сделали то, о чём я писал в комментарии выше %)

Comment: Ага, определил, что Linux Mint 17.2 собрана на базе Ubuntu 14.04. Значит в адрес репозиториев я должен написать trusty. Вышла такая строчка - 
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ trusty-pgdg main, но ошибки те же (

Comment: @MaximCherevatov обновите вопрос, покажите что теперь.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: по адресу http://ppa.launchpad.net/pitti/postgresql/ubuntu/dists/ нет пакетов для trusty.

Comment: @KoVadim спасибо за улику, описал ситуацию.

Comment: @MaximCherevatov обновил ответ. **tl;dr -- откатывайте всё, что сказали сделать в той инструкции %)**